# Javascript Regex not formatting each instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am making a simple JavaScript based WYSIWYG editor using regular expressions to do the conversion to html.

This is the javascript conversion method I am using

```
message = message.replace(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

It converts text surrounded with two ** to bold.
The issue is that it does not do that for every instance.
Instead it does it from the first instance of ** to the last.

So `**bold text** **bold text**`

Gives me

**bold text***  ***bold text**

```
<b>bold text* *bold text</b>
```

Instead of

```
<b>bold text</b> <b>bold text</b>
```

How can I set it up to convert each instance instead of grouping them together?

Comment: Try this: `message = message.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the quantifier to `.*?` to make it not greedy:

```
message = message.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
//                                ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current regex is kind of nice and captures any character after your first two stars, since .* matches anything regex will keep eating your data until it finds the last occurrence of **, which is at the end and that's why you get the results youre having.

Try replacing it with:

```
message = message.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

This little ? makes the regex non-greedy which means that it will stop at the first occurrence of the two stars.
Or you could do something like:

```
message = message.replace(/\*\*([A-Za-z0-9_- ]+)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `(.*)` is capturing everything. This should solve your problem:

```
\*\*([^\*]+)\*\*
```

The problem with this, though, is that it will match this: `**fjffj**` but not this: `**ffff*gggg**`